# Does every Taylor series for $\cos$ only have even exponents?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

S. Colley, Vector Calculus, p.246 writes:
[image]

but isn't $\cos$ an even function?  I am baffled. Can you please explain?

Comment: That thing about even exponents for even function is for a Taylor centered at $x=0$. Yours is centered at $x=\pi/2$. Your expansion also corresponds to a Taylor at $x=0$ for $\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=-\sin(x)$ which is not even. It is odd.

Comment: Inspect the graph of $\cos$ around $\frac{\pi}{2}$. You will see that it is odd about that point.

Comment: You know $|x|$ is an even function of $x$, but are probably aren't surprised to know that $|x-1|$ is not even. Same thing here.

Comment: @MPW That's helpful.  So should this Taylor series be viewed as being for $f(x) = \cos (x - \pi/2)$ and not for $f(x) = \cos x$?

Comment: No, this is the Taylor series for $\cos x$, just around $x=\pi/2$ instead of $x=0$. Look up Taylor series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will have only even exponents e.g. if you write the Taylor series around the point $x_0 = 0$. So there's no contradiction here. We're around a different point here $x_0 = \pi / 2$.

Comment: It will also be the case at $n\pi$.